# Order by with order of writing columns

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to order by first `featured_due` then `nard_apply_date_due` and then `post_date`

```
$join .= " LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT post_id, meta_value as featured_due
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE meta_key =  'featured' ) AS DD
            ON $wpdb->posts.ID = DD.post_id ";


$join .= " LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT post_id, meta_value as nard_apply_date_due
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE meta_key =  'nard_ads_apply_date' ) AS naad
            ON $wpdb->posts.ID = naad.post_id ";
```

Sort code is:

```
$orderby =  " metaKey1 desc, metaKey2 desc, $wpdb->posts.post_date desc ";
```

But I get wrong order.

My final sql query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT post_id, meta_value as featured_due FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'featured' ) AS DD 
    ON wp_posts.ID = DD.post_id LEFT JOIN ( SELECT post_id, meta_value as nard_apply_date_due 
    FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'nard_ads_apply_date' ) AS naad ON wp_posts.ID = naad.post_id 
    JOIN ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'custom_field_ID_2' and (meta_value <= 100000000000 and meta_value >= 0)) AS JJ 
    ON wp_posts.ID = JJ.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (72,189,190,191,192,232,233,234) ) 
    AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'closed' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '0' ) )
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'project' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
    AND (1=1 AND (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%%' OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%%') )
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY featured_due desc, nard_apply_date_due desc, wp_posts.post_date desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

i get result - but it have random order! i want featured_due in first and then nard_apply_date_due

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Do you get the result in wrong order, or do you get an error message?

Comment: @jarlh i get wrong order.

Comment: @jarlh please see my update thanks

Comment: update your question add  a proper  data sample .. you actual result and your expected  result

Comment: I could be wrong but shouldn't there be an `ORDER BY` keyword(s) somewhere in `$orderby`... or is the sql still incomplete? (I don't know php, btw).

Comment: You just print the string variable that comes with the final query then cross check.

Comment: @SumeshTG I Update question.

Comment: @scaisEdge I Update question.

Comment: @JohnLaw  Update question.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY DD.featured_due desc`

Comment: With respect, it's absolutely necessary for us to see some sample data from your `featured_due` and `nard_apply_date_due` items, or we won't be able to help you. `wp_postmeta` doesn't use `DATE` or `DATETIME` fields in its `meta_value` columns, it holds text strings.  So your dates could be represented lots of different ways. You can't `ORDER BY ` dates unless they have a uniform representation. Please [edit] your question.